# Achieving Greensock Tweenmax like Performance|Architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, gsap

After searching a lot on "Why greensock tweenmax animation is faster comparing to jQuery animation" google I got some answers on SO and greensock forums I didn't get comprehensive answer.

However in one answer there was a line that says

> There are architectural choices, memory management, lookup
>   efficiencies, and plenty of regular JS code optimizations at play
>   suggestion

I didn't get those parameters.

So question is

- how to achieve GSAP like performance for jQuery([700 pound gorilla](https://greensock.com/jquery/)) applications?
- Rewriting jQuery is not an option. so what are other options to go for.
- Can this memory management and lookup choices etc, be done in heavy jQuery application?

Correct/Suggest if I am wrong.

Comment: take a look at [velocityjs](http://velocityjs.org/)

Comment: sure, I will checkout

Comment: why not ask GreenSock? http://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/

Comment: there are already some answers, and that explains terms as written in quotes in question. Not an comprehensive.

Comment: If you're looking to get GSAP-like performance in a jQuery-based project, it probably doesn't get much simpler than this: http://greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin. It essentially hijacks jQuery.animate() and sends those animations to GSAP, thus you get the extra features and performance.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the that. I'll definitely try. Though I need to look at source code.

Comment: An obvious solution would be simply to use GSAP. Is there some reason you're trying to avoid that? It would take much, much too long to explain every optimization choice in GSAP that I made (I authored it). You said rewriting jQuery is not an option - are you trying to create your own library and leverage the optimizations GSAP has made or something? Just trying to understand why you're focused on jQuery and not just using GSAP to get the performance you need.

Comment: @Jack GSAP is the solution. Fact is I am curious and want to know & learn what GSAP guys (you) has done such a significant (20x) performance improvement. As a JavaScript lover I would like to learn and write such code on my own, that's it. Have you written any book on JS, if so, please suggest. (I'm not working on any animation task with jQuery or GSAP either.)

Comment: @shyammakwana.me ah, okay. Thanks for clarifying. Makes sense. And no, I haven't written a book yet. Perhaps one day I'll do some writing about the "secrets" of writing high-performance JS. Lots of experimentation, plus I stumbled across plenty of info on the web over the years. GSAP employs many, many strategies for optimizing performance; I wish I could just give you a super quick summary. Good luck with your projects, and keep being curious :)

Comment: @Jack Wow, that you talked about something real cool, put in all the real juice into that, Good luck with your book. Will be waiting for that (I would like to feel being Ninja ;)). Thank you so much for your time.